# Item Limit property is not working on Announcement Web part (at Home page)

Tags: sharepoint-online, view

I am using an Announcement app and modified the view to set **Item Limit** to 2 (it was working), but when I add this app to home page its shows scroll bar instead of next button at the bottom of app.